# Confusion about byte strings and base64 encoding in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64, byte

In Python 3, lets say I have a string of bytes:

```
my_byte_string = b'\x07L\x1b\xa8b\x8f\xba\x1b{\x1c\x16CwW\xa5\xae!\x93MY'
```

and I use the base64 module to get this:

```
my_base64_string = base64.b64encode(my_byte_string)

print(my_base64_string)

b'B0wbqGKPuht7HBZDd1elriGTTVk='
```

When I do this, I am confused about what happens to the '\' characters. I know that they indicate separation of different bytes, but are they being encoded by b64encode like the other characters, or are they being ignored?

Comment: You are confusing embedded special characters with real characters.  A simpler example would be what happens to `\n` - that is not stored as two characters but as the character equivalent of  a newline for your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'\'` character doesn't indicate the separation of different bytes, it is a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), which is used to escape characters with special meaning. In your case, you use `\x<hex>`, which tells the Python interpreter to place the **byte value** you specified into the String. Thus, these bytes that you sequentially specify (`0x07L`, `0x1b`, ...) are encoded to base64, and nothing else.

To verify this, look at the hexadecimal representation of your binary data:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(my_byte_string)
b'074c1ba8628fba1b7b1c16437757a5ae21934d59'
```